# JMeter showing wrong thread count in distributed testing

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 2.13 and have 2 thread groups,for each thread group i assigned 25 users.
I am running the test in distribution mode using 2 machines as slaves.

But the total user count is showing as 50 only,But it should be 100 as per my understading(50*2 slaves=100 Users,Correct me if am wrong)

I have added some listeners by adding JMeter plugins and they are also showing the total user count as 50 only.

Looking forward for answer...

Regards.

Comment: Hi UBIK,your are correct one of injecter was not reporting.Thanx ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must put in Thread Group name some information to uniquely identify each injector:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/

For example:

> ${__machineName()}_My Threadgroup name

Based on your last comment, your issue is most probably that 1 injector(server) is not able to contact controller (client) to report its progress.

Check logs of each jmeter-server.

Comment: Hi UBIC, thanx for the response,JMeter GUI showing total user count in top right corner as 50 only(Eg it appears like 50/50)how to get the correct count(in this case 100/100)